# Is there a way to dispose tensors in tf.Model object?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I'm building an interactive app in which users can play around with the parameters of a model. After new parameters are specified, I no longer need the old tf.Model object and the associated tensors. Is there an equivalent of tf.Tensor.dispose() for tf.Model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, `tf.disposeVariables()` is what you want.

this command is available after 0.11.1 version.

https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.11.1/#disposeVariables

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing i can think of is `tf.reset_default_graph()`, although it blows away all ops and tensors, as well as all variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your entire block in a `tf.tidy()` it will dispose of all tensors except for those returned by the block.

https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.9.0/#tidy